# Is it possible that each condition in "case when" has a different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like below

```
select
    COALESCE(Clinic,'total') as Clinic,
    sum(Non_Billable) as Non_Billable,
    sum(initial_Non_Billable) as initial_Non_Billable,
    sum(Non_Billable)/NULLIF(sum(initial_Non_Billable),0) as Non_Billable_initial_revenue
FROM (
    select
        businesses.label as Clinic,
    sum(CASE
        WHEN appointment_types.category IN (
            'Others',
            'Non-Billable')
            and appointment_types.name like '%initial%'
        then invoices.net_amount ELSE 0 END)
        as Non_Billable,
    count(CASE
        WHEN appointment_types.category IN (
            'Others',
            'Non-Billable')
            and appointment_types.name like '%initial%'
        then appointment_types.name ELSE null END)
        as initial_Non_Billable
    
    FROM
        individual_appointments
        INNER join appointment_types on
        appointment_types.id = individual_appointments.appointment_type_id
        inner join invoices on
        invoices.appointment_id = individual_appointments.id
        inner join businesses on
        businesses.id = individual_appointments.business_id
    group by
        businesses.label,
        appointment_types.name,
        appointment_types.category,
        invoices.net_amount
)x
group by
    ROLLUP(Clinic);
```

is it possible for each condition in "case when then" to have a different table?

example: for "Non_Billable" only want from individual_appointment, appointment_types, invoices and businesses table only.

while "initial_Non_Billable" only wants from individual_appointment, appointment_types, and businesses table.

can it be like that?

If possible, how? can anyone give an example?

Comment: Because of the grouping on `invoices.net_amount` it would be nice if you can create a [mre], (to include some sample input and desired output). Now one can only guess what should happen with the invoices on "initial_Non_Billable" things.

Comment: What is your DBMS? You should always tag SQL request with your DBMS in order to get answers appropriate for your DBMS.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the correction, sorry I'm wrong, I've changed it

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i use metabase

Comment: Metabase is a tool that can work with a variety of DBMS (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, MySQL, SQL Server, ...). It is not a DBMS itself. So the question remains: which DBMS are you using with Metabase?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner oh sorry i meant using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, I suppose the problem here is that there can be many invoices per appointment, so when you join invoices you get appointments multifold which also multiplies your counts.

You don't really want to join invoices hence, but invoice sums. I.e. aggregate before joining.

Then, you are only interested in non-billable appointments, so you can put that criteria into your `ON` clauses and outer join in order to get clinics without such appointments.

```
select
  coalesce(b.label, 'total') as clinic,
  coalesce(sum(i.total_net_amount), 0) as initial_non_billable_sum,
  count(at.id) as initial_non_billable_count,
  avg(i.total_net_amount) as initial_non_billable_average
from businesses b
left join individual_appointments ia on ia.business_id = b.id
left join appointment_types at on at.id = ia.appointment_type_id
                              and at.category in ('others', 'non-billable')
                              and at.name like '%initial%'
left join
(
  select appointment_id, sum(net_amount) as total_net_amount
  from invoices
  group by appointment_id
) i on i.appointment_id = ia.id
group by rollup(b.label)
order by b.label nulls last;
```

Comment: I just want to know the total number of appointments that have the condition appointment_types.category IN ('Others','Non-Billable') and appointment_types.name like '%initial%' from the table individual_appointment, appointment_types, invoices and businesses as "Non_Billable" . And also I want to know the total net_amount revenue based on which has the condition appointment_types.category IN ('Others','Non-Billable') and appointment_types.name like '%initial%' from table individual_appointment, appointment_types, invoices and businesses as "initial_Non_Billable" .

Comment: Then in the end I want to do the calculation that is "initial_Non_Billable" divided by "Non_Billable" as "Non_Billable_initial_revenue"

Comment: so I need invoices table for "Non_Billable" calculation only, not "initial_Non_Billable"

Comment: My query gets the total number of appointments that match your condition (`count(at.id) `). My query also gets the total net_amount for these conditions (`coalesce(sum(i.total_net_amount), 0)`). The sum divided by the count is the average (`avg(i.total_net_amount)`). The invoices table doesn't affect the appointment count. Is the problem with my query that it gets the average appointment net amount and not the average invoice net amount? Or is there some other issue?

Comment: Great answer, but if I want to add other conditions like, WHEN appointment_types.category IN ( 'Tele Health- Ex Phys','Tele Health-OT','Tele Health- Physio','Tele Health- Speech Pathology') and appointment_types.name like '%initial%' as Telehealth, to find the number of appointments and revenue too, where should I put it and how?

Comment: Then you are back to inner joins and the conditions moved from the `ON` clause back inside the aggregation function like you had them. The main difference between your query and mine is that I aggregate the invoices before joining them.